# the css property "clear" leaves a huge empty space

Tags: css

I am simply using a div of this nature to clear an area after floats:

```
.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

however, I am seeing it is causing a big space in my formatting and I'm not sure how to rid of it. what do you think may be happening?

thank you!

Comment: You need to setup a sample page and link it here. Most probably, one of the containers above it has a margin/padding

Comment: This can't be answered in its current form. As people have pointed out, needs more HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a line height , it should fix the problem.

Is it happening only on IE , if so add line height

do something like this

```
.clear {
        clear: both;
        height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: @DiegoJancic Then check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166716/unexplained-white-space-when-using-clearboth). There seem to be many similar questions on SO. :) The one I linked to worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, the solution is to add this to the group's parent; that is the element that is causing the problems:

overflow: auto

i.e.:

```
<div style="overflow: auto">
   <div style="float: right">Testing</div>
   <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just apply the `clear: both` attribute to the next content element (i.e. div) instead of creating an empty div (which I'm assuming that you are doing).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/ArDhF/1/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with several small left-floating tables next to each other. The clear div afterwards took a lot of white space without having any height, nor padding or margin.

The solution: Wrap all tables within a div, then assign `overflow-hidden` to that div and (this is important) a value for the `height`.

E.g.

```
.tablecontainer {
    height: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```