# Unexplained white space when using clear:both

Tags: html, css

I'm building a Joomla 1.7 website and I'm using a gallery plugin. This works out real nice except for one problem. In the gallery plugin you can insert a description that is displayed on top of all the images, but whenever I use this I get an enormous amount of whitespace.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Bam.jpg[image]

The HTML:

```
<div id="phocagallery" class="pg-category-view" style="width:800px;margin: auto;">
   <div class="pg-category-view-desc">Pictures of the Roskilde Family</div>
   <div id="pg-icons"></div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
   <div class="phocagallery-box-file" style="height:158px; width:120px;">
   <div class="phocagallery-box-file" style="height:158px; width:120px;">
   <div class="phocagallery-box-file" style="height:158px; width:120px;">
   <div class="phocagallery-box-file" style="height:158px; width:120px;">
   <div class="phocagallery-box-file" style="height:158px; width:120px;">
```

If I remove the  the white space disappears. I look in my css with firebug but I can't for the life of me figure out why it is giving me this white-space. I used the Yahoo css-reset.

EDIT: CSS

div id="phocagallery" class="pg-category-view":

```
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, code, form, fieldset, legend, input, button, textarea, blockquote, th, td, p 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
    body {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
```

Anybody have a clue?

Comment: We need the relevant CSS styles, too. Or a link to the actual page.

Comment: What about posting: pg-category-view-desc for the actual CSS, somewhere they've defined the white space.

Comment: It it not reserved space by the plugin maybe for buttons or potential for text?

Comment: all add the CSS, one second :)

Comment: have you tried using Firebug or Chrome inspector to check what that space actually is? It is as easy as 'rolling your cursor over it' and it would highlight the code in question.

Comment: that wouldn't work for some reason, that's why I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You must have a sidebar on the left or the right with a floating element in it (or which is floating itself).

The clear:both causes the element to be under that floating element.

See the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Razw/

One solution is to set `overflow: hidden` on #phocagallery or a parent of the `clear:both` element.

Comment: This is actually it! Thank you, now at least I know why it was doing it! My entire sidebar is floated and indeed it falls right below the sidebar, I had not even noticed. Is there a way to make it ignore my floated sidebar?

Comment: One solution is to set overflow: hidden on #phocagallery or a parent of the clear:both element.

Comment: Yes, this helped me out too!

Answer (score 1):

the class pg-category-view-desc probably give the div float:left or float:right and it also has a fixed height and the clear apply the div height

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
.clear
{
  height:0px;
  clear:both;
}
```