# Extra space at the bottom of div float container

Tags: css, css-float

This is the current setup:

```
<div id="youtubelatestnews">
    <div class="box youtubebox">
    </div>

    <div class="latestnews">
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

But the problem is the container `<div>` which is "youtubelatestnews" has too much space at the bottom.

Here's the site: http://voila.easywebprojects.com/

The `<div>`s I'm referring to are the sneak peek & Latest News portion.

Comment: It looks fine to me on IE9. Are you taking about the space between the "Latest News" section and the "Information, Customer Service, My Account" footer?

Comment: It seems your 'clear' div is going to the bottom of the youtubelatestnews div. Do you actually need it if it's an empty div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the extra space is the clear div, which will clear below the elements on the left also.

You can remove the clear div, and use `overflow: hidden;` on the #youtubelatestnews div. As you don't have a height specified for it, the overflow style will only make the element contain its children.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `float:left;` style to `youtubelatestnews` div, it worked for me ;-)

Comment: Yes it worked! I wonder why I needed to add float:left; it's the main container so I didn't think of adding the float: left;

Comment: Yes it looks a little bit wierd to me too.. maybe someone will explain it here later or post more logical solution. Anyway if you use mine workaround at the end, please accept my answer ;-)

Comment: @laurize & gatekeeper; give float:left to the content div because contentleft div have a float check this for explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166716/unexplained-white-space-when-using-clearboth

Comment: @sandeep thanks for explain.. so right solution is what Guffa suggested or just adding that float to wrapper too as I posted in my answer?

Comment: @gatekeeper; Guffa answer is a quick solution but it's not explain why that empty space comes & in your solution you give the answer but you did not know why that's happen.

Answer (score 0):

The margin-bottom on `.box-product > div` plus the margin-bottom on `.box` are combining.

Answer (score 0):

The extra space can be caused by the default height of clear item sometimes,
Try to add `height:0px` for the clear .

https://jsfiddle.net/8zpt7tm3/