# Using clear:both creates a gap under the item

Tags: css

First of all, I did read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684951/the-css-property-clear-leaves-a-huge-empty-space) question which lead me to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166716/unexplained-white-space-when-using-clearboth) question. The overall answer to those questions were to add `overflow: auto;` to the parent, but that actually created a small scroll bar in Firefox.

My problem is I have an element inside my content that I'm needing to float, but I also have a floating sidebar. So when I use the `clear: both;` on the element in my content, it creates a gap that goes to the end of the sidebar. I'll post my code, although it's very simple:

```
<div class="post-recipe">

<div class="post-recipe-1"><strong>Time:</strong> <?php the_field('prep_time'); ?></div>

<div class="post-recipe-2"><strong>Servings:</strong> <?php the_field('makes'); ?></div>

<div class="post-recipe-3"><?php the_field('ingredients'); ?></div>

<div class="post-recipe-4"><?php the_field('directions'); ?></div>

</div>
```

My CSS, again, very basic

```
.post-recipe { 
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.post-recipe-1 {
float: left;
}

.post-recipe-2 {
float: right;
}

.post-recipe-3 {
clear: both;
}
```

I had already built the design, which functions correctly before I decided to backtrack and add this bit in. I'm actually considering using a table to format this bit, but before I did that, I thought I'd ask my question here. Again, I did try `overflow: auto;` in the parent, but it created a scrollbar. Adding that DID remove the gap, but I can't have that scrollbar. I also tried adding `height: 0;` to my clearfix, but it did nothing. Is there any other way to float the first two elements, clearing the float without it creating the gap?

[HERE](http://dn4l.illstudios.com/?p=77) is a link to the page in question, if you look underneath the Prep Time and Servings section, you'll see the gap.

Comment: Could you post code relavant to your problem? For example the generated HTML.

Comment: I can't see the gap with what is provided... [this example seems fine](http://jsbin.com/qeganoxefo/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Sounds like you may want to croup your non-sidebar content in a container.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to post my entire code, so I'll just provide a link to the site.

Comment: Though there will be a learning curve, a much more flexible approach to creating this layout would be [CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), as opposed to using `float`s or `table`s. [This complete guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) breaks it down very well, with pictures and code samples.

Comment: I would hopefully like to fix this without having to change a majority of my code (I know I could just apply it to this section, but that feels.. wrong). Thanks though, I'll definitely be reading that page closely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this gets rid of the gap

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Should give you the same effect without the scrollbar.

Comment: I tried that too, it didn't do anything to the gap at all. Overflow: Auto; removed the gap, but created the scroll bar, Overflow: Hidden; didn't change anything.

Comment: Or, apparently I didn't upload something correctly, because adding this again solved my problem! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.  As mjswensen said, there is a better way to do this.  This solution is sort of hacky, but it produces the desired effect.  
I realize most of us don't live in a world where we can always do it the right way.  Sometimes we have to live with what works.